# Memory leak in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, ios-simulator, instruments

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but it's possible to have a memory leak in the Simulator?

i was trying to figure why my app keeps crashing and the Instruments detected a memory leak will I was running my app. But now, I've started to record after open my app and I've a leak as well.

Here's the image:
[image]

Is that normal? And how do I fix it?

UPDATE: I've closed the Xcode, open it without open any project, open Instruments and Simulator, record it and I've a memory leak without even touch the simulator. How is that possible?!

Comment: code pleaaaaaaassseeee

Comment: Find a leak in code and fix it - if you show us a code which is causing it - maybe we can tell you more. Btw. it's never a good idea to test memory and performance on simulator

Comment: I don't even know which part of the code is causing the leak.

Comment: Please mention that your code is in ARC or not ?

Comment: @Sam yes, it's in ARC

Comment: product->Analyze code and solve memory leak

Comment: @payal I've tried it but it didn't solve the leak

Answer (score 0):

It could be your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19490482/944027

But I don't think that profiling simulator is a good idea. The question about difference in profiling iPhone 4 and simulator: [Profiling memory leaks with Instruments- huge difference between iPhone 4 and iOS 5 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468662/profiling-memory-leaks-with-instruments-huge-difference-between-iphone-4-and-io).
The problem in different architecture.